# cancel log in instead of creating a new account through facebook

Tags: parse-platform, swift2, facebook-ios-sdk, xcode7

The following code will create a new account if there is no account created yet, but instead i would like to move user to the sign up page and ask him to create an account instead of creating an account immediately. What changes should i do?

```
PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions) {
  (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if let user = user {
    if user.isNew {
      println("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
    } else {
      println("User logged in through Facebook!")
    }
  } else {
    println("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, and the sign up view is also inappropriate as it will ask for a password which isn't required. Instead you should show a new view asking for additional details then set those details onto the new user and save it.